# PHP & Jquery Creating Multiple Dynamic Select Lists with Probable Conditional Behaviors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The title is a bit much so let me break this down. What I am trying to accomplish here is selecting an option from select 1 (onChange) retrieves the prebuilt select for select 2 from an external php script. Same for 2 -> 3 and 3 -> 4. I know how to do this, perhaps not efficiently, but, I can get it done.

The problem I crashed into was, the 3rd select is not always an option. This is a problem because the 4th select is the end result I need. The second select in this case will give me the ID's to create select 4 instead. Make sense?

**HTML:**

```
<td>
    <select name="collectionID" id="bpCollection" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Collection</option>
            <?PHP echo optionsFromDatabase();?>
    </select>
</td>
<td><select name="bpClass"id="bpClass" class="form-control"></select></td>
<td><select name="bpFaction"id="bpFaction" class="form-control"></select></td>
<td><select name="bpID"id="bpID" class="form-control"></select></td>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
<script>

    $("#bpCollection").change(function() {
        $("#bpClass").load("inc/api/auto.php?type=class&choice=" + $("#bpCollection").val());
    });

    $("#bpClass").change(function() {
        $("#bpFaction").load("inc/api/auto.php?type=faction&choice=" + $("#bpClass").val());
    });

    $("#bpFaction").change(function() {
        $("#bpID").load("inc/api/auto.php?type=blueprint&choice=" + $("#bpFaction").val());
    });


</script>
```

As Previously stated this does work perfectly.

**Auto.php**

```
$group = $db->escape($_GET['type']);
$choice = $db->escape($_GET['choice']);

$list = ''; 

switch ($group) { 

    case 'blueprint':

        $db->where('marketGroupID',$choice);
        $db->orderBy('typeName','ASC');
        $map = $db->get('invTypes');

        foreach ( $map as $val ) { 

            $list .= '<option value="'.$val['typeID'].'">'.$val['typeName'].'</option>';

        }

        break;

    default:

        $db->where('parentGroupID',$choice);
        $db->orderBy('marketGroupName','ASC');
        $map = $db->get('invmarketgroups');

        foreach ( $map as $val ) { 

            $list .= '<option value="'.$val['marketGroupID'].'">'.$val['marketGroupName'].'</option>';

        }



}

echo $list;
```

This works perfectly, except. `#bpFaction` is not always an option where it can't populate since `#bpClass` holds the ID options for `#bpID`. I can select the `#bpClass` select option and will need to jump straight to `#bpID`. I think a good part of the problem I have is that I don't visualize the code needed on either end to make this work properly. Do I need to make the jquery do this, do I need to change auto.php, or both?

Do you have any thoughts on how best to do it?

Comment: How do you exactly determine you don't need option 3? Is it when you have no results from the db or only one?

Comment: I would use Ajax requests instead of using jQuery `load` function. This way you can either get the next select box options OR get a result back stating you reached the end and handle that in JS (Ajax can process JSON responses instead of just HTML allowing you to communicate states and information more efficiently for things like this). EDIT: I built this exact same setup but more complicated about a month ago.

Comment: @Michel that is exactly right. When #bpClass fires the auto.php wont have any database references to that ID. That is how we will know there is no #bpFaction, only #bpID

Comment: @Skylord123 I am much less knowledgable about Ajax than I should be. Can I trouble you for some sample code to reference?

Comment: Bah, edit time lapsed. Perhaps a setup like `$('#bpCollection, #bpClass, #bpFaction').change(function() { ` to watch all select options and perform my calls to auto.php by capturing the `document.getElementById("#bpWhatever").value;` in one single function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommended using Ajax with JSON above. Here I will go more in-depth of how to do that. I will be writing this sample using States, Cities, and Jurisdictions as the select box types.

We will be using one controller in PHP for all select  boxes (just like yours above) except we will be re-writing it to return JSON instead. I don't know what framework you are using so I just wrote a sample of what it would look like:

```
    // if no state passed in, return list
    if(!$stateId = $request->get('state')) {
        $loadedStatesFromDb = ...; // states loaded from DB

        // if your $loadedCitiesFromDb is an array of classes we need to format it into a flat array for JSON
        $states = [];
        foreach($loadedStatesFromDb as $state) {
            $states[$state->getId()] = $state->getName();
        }

        // your framework may require a different method of passing json data
        return json_encode([
            'result' => 'ok', // we pass this so the Ajax jquery call can check it returned successfully
            'states' => $states
        ]);
    }

    // if no city passed in, load cities for the selected state
    if(!$cityId = $request->get('city')) {
        $loadedCitiesFromDb = ...; // cities loaded from DB for $stateId

        // if your $loadedCitiesFromDb is an array of classes we need to format it into a flat array for JSON
        $cities = [];
        foreach($loadedCitiesFromDb as $city) {
            $cities[$city->getId()] = $city->getName();
        }

        // your framework may require a different method of passing json data
        return json_encode([
            'result' => 'ok', // we pass this so the Ajax jquery call can check it returned successfully
            'cities' => $cities
        ]);
    }

    // if no jurisdiction selected, load list
    if(!$jurisdictionId = $request->get('jurisdiction')) {
        $loadedJurisdictionsFromDb = ...; // jurisdictions loaded from DB for $cityId

        // if your $loadedCitiesFromDb is an array of classes we need to format it into a flat array for JSON
        $jurisdictions = [];
        foreach($loadedJurisdictionsFromDb as $jurisdiction) {
            $jurisdictions[$jurisdiction->getId()] = $jurisdiction->getName();
        }

        // your framework may require a different method of passing json data
        return json_encode([
            'result' => 'ok', // we pass this so the Ajax jquery call can check it returned successfully
            'jurisdictions' => $jurisdictions
        ]);
    }
```

And this is what your view would sort of look like (untested, but generally how you would do it):

```
    <select name="state" id="state-select"></select>
    <select name="city" id="city-select"></select>
    <select name="jurisdiction" id="jurisdiction-select"></select>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function _load_select_boxes(e) {
            if(
                $("#state-select").val() && $("#city-select").val() && $("jurisdiction-select").val() && // if we have an item selected in all select boxes
                typeof e !== 'undefined' && e.target.id == 'jurisdiction-select' // if the select box that triggered the event is the last one
            ) {
                _select_box_completed('jurisdiction', $("jurisdiction-select").val());
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '/where/you/load/select/boxes',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#state-select, #city-select, #jurisdiction-select").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json', // what server will return
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.result === 'ok') {
                        if(typeof data.states !== 'undefined') {
                            // no need to reset options for the first select (unless we will be re-loading it without selecting a value)

                            // set select box options using the array of cities
                            for(var stateId in data.states) {
                                var stateName = data.states[stateId];
                                $("#city-select").append('<option value="' + stateId + '">' + stateName + '</option>')
                            }
                        } else if(typeof data.cities !== 'undefined') {
                            // reset select box
                            $('#city-select').find('option').remove();

                            // set select box options using the array of cities
                            for(var cityId in data.cities) {
                                var cityName = data.cities[cityId];
                                $("#city-select").append('<option value="' + cityId + '">' + cityName + '</option>')
                            }
                        } else if(typeof data.jurisdictions !== 'undefined') {
                            if(!data.jurisdictions.length) {
                                // no jurisdictions returned so we reached end
                                _select_box_completed('city', $("#city-select").val());
                            } else {
                                // reset select box
                                $('#jurisdiction-select').find('option').remove();

                                // set select box options using the array of jurisdictions
                                for(var jurisdictionId in data.jurisdictions) {
                                    var jurisdictionName = data.jurisdictions[jurisdictionId];
                                    $("#jurisdiction-select").append('<option value="' + jurisdictionId + '">' + jurisdictionName + '</option>')
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // handle error for app
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // handle error for app
                }
            });
        }

        function _select_box_completed(type, id) {
            // fired when we have selected as far as we can go
        }

        $(function(){
            // this runs when page finishes loading, so we can load in the defaults and set events on the select boxes
            $("#state-select, #city-select, #jurisdiction-select").on('change', function(e){
                _load_select_boxes(e);
            });

            _load_select_boxes();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help me move forward. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without changing much code is make your switch a function, build in a condition and call it again with changed parameters if that condition is met.

```
$list= myswitch($db, $group, $choice);

function myswitch($db, $group, $choice){
   $list='';
   switch ($group) { 
      case 'blueprint':
      ...
      break;

     default:
        $db->where('parentGroupID',$choice);
        $db->orderBy('marketGroupName','ASC');
        $map = $db->get('invmarketgroups');

       //*** CONDITION HERE ***
       //IF condition met: set new variables
       if($choice === ... && $map === ...)){
          $group="xxx";
          $choice="yyy";

          //call the function again with new values
          $list = myswitch($db, $group, $choice);
          }
      //ELSE create normal list
      else{
          foreach ( $map as $val ) { 
             $list.= ....
             }
          }
   return list;
 }
```

Comment: Sure, I've thought of this. Then with my jquery out front how would I tell #bpClass to skip #faction?